# laravel push relation data into model

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I have export function that it gets `model data` and adds some of it's relationship data as array under it.

The issue is that relationship data array are wrong all the time.

## Example

`real data`

[image: one]

`data that I get in export file`

```
<NMEXML EximID="13037" BranchCode="1450645381" ACCOUNTANTCOPYID="">
  <TRANSACTIONS OnError="CONTINUE">
    <WTRAN operation="Add" REQUESTID="1">
      <TRANSFERID>3</TRANSFERID>
      <TRANSACTIONID/>
      <TRANSFERNO>3</TRANSFERNO>
      <TRANSFERDATE>2020-08-22</TRANSFERDATE>
      <DESCRIPTION>232547544</DESCRIPTION>
      <FROMWHID>8</FROMWHID>
      <TOWHID/>
      <FROMWHADDRESS/>
      <TOWHADDRESS/>
      <ITEMLINE operation="Add">
        <KeyID>1</KeyID>
        <ITEMNO>6951919696</ITEMNO>
        <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
        <ITEMUNIT>Unit</ITEMUNIT>
        <UNITRATIO>1</UNITRATIO>
        <ITEMRESERVED1/>
        <ITEMRESERVED2/>
        <ITEMRESERVED3/>
        <ITEMRESERVED4/>
        <ITEMRESERVED5/>
        <ITEMRESERVED6/>
        <ITEMRESERVED7/>
        <ITEMRESERVED8/>
        <ITEMRESERVED9/>
        <ITEMRESERVED10/>
        <UNITPRICE>2500000</UNITPRICE>
        <QTYCONTROL>0</QTYCONTROL>
        <SNHISTORY operation="Ret">
          <SERIALNUMBER>658532125</SERIALNUMBER>
          <EXPIREDDATE>2020-08-21</EXPIREDDATE>
          <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
          <SNSIGN>-1</SNSIGN>
        </SNHISTORY>
      </ITEMLINE>
      <ITEMLINE operation="Add">
        <KeyID>2</KeyID>
        <ITEMNO>9532880976</ITEMNO>
        <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
        <ITEMUNIT>Pcs</ITEMUNIT>
        <UNITRATIO>1</UNITRATIO>
        <ITEMRESERVED1/>
        <ITEMRESERVED2/>
        <ITEMRESERVED3/>
        <ITEMRESERVED4/>
        <ITEMRESERVED5/>
        <ITEMRESERVED6/>
        <ITEMRESERVED7/>
        <ITEMRESERVED8/>
        <ITEMRESERVED9/>
        <ITEMRESERVED10/>
        <UNITPRICE>50000000</UNITPRICE>
        <QTYCONTROL>0</QTYCONTROL>
        <SNHISTORY operation="Ret">
          <SERIALNUMBER>658532125</SERIALNUMBER>
          <EXPIREDDATE>2020-08-21</EXPIREDDATE>
          <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
          <SNSIGN>-1</SNSIGN>
        </SNHISTORY>
        <SNHISTORY operation="Ret">
          <SERIALNUMBER>454874152</SERIALNUMBER>
          <EXPIREDDATE>2020-08-21</EXPIREDDATE>
          <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
          <SNSIGN>-1</SNSIGN>
        </SNHISTORY>
      </ITEMLINE>
      <ITEMLINE operation="Add">
        <KeyID>3</KeyID>
        <ITEMNO>2124086153</ITEMNO>
        <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
        <ITEMUNIT>Box</ITEMUNIT>
        <UNITRATIO>1</UNITRATIO>
        <ITEMRESERVED1/>
        <ITEMRESERVED2/>
        <ITEMRESERVED3/>
        <ITEMRESERVED4/>
        <ITEMRESERVED5/>
        <ITEMRESERVED6/>
        <ITEMRESERVED7/>
        <ITEMRESERVED8/>
        <ITEMRESERVED9/>
        <ITEMRESERVED10/>
        <UNITPRICE>23658000</UNITPRICE>
        <QTYCONTROL>0</QTYCONTROL>
        <SNHISTORY operation="Ret">
          <SERIALNUMBER>658532125</SERIALNUMBER>
          <EXPIREDDATE>2020-08-21</EXPIREDDATE>
          <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
          <SNSIGN>-1</SNSIGN>
        </SNHISTORY>
        <SNHISTORY operation="Ret">
          <SERIALNUMBER>454874152</SERIALNUMBER>
          <EXPIREDDATE>2020-08-21</EXPIREDDATE>
          <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
          <SNSIGN>-1</SNSIGN>
        </SNHISTORY>
        <SNHISTORY operation="Ret">
          <SERIALNUMBER>232547544</SERIALNUMBER>
          <EXPIREDDATE>2020-08-22</EXPIREDDATE>
          <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
          <SNSIGN>-1</SNSIGN>
        </SNHISTORY>
      </ITEMLINE>
    </WTRAN>
  </TRANSACTIONS>
</NMEXML>
```

#### Explanation

`ITEMLINE` are array of my model rows

`SNHISTORY` are model relationship data (screenshot above) that I need them to be arrays as well and most importantly in correct relations.

As you see my `SNHISTORY`'s are misplaced in `ITEMLINE`'s and printed in extra.

## Code

> `SNHISTORY` parts are commented for your better understanding

```
public function internalTransit(Request $request) {
    $internalTransits = Transit::with(['barcodes', 'barcodes.outlet', 'barcodes.product', 'barcodes.product.outer', 'sender', 'receiver', 'fromOutlet', 'toOutlet'])->get();

    //data here
    $array = [];
    foreach($internalTransits as $key => $item) {

        // SNHISTORY data

        // collect the data
        $serials = [];
        $ITEMUNIT = '';
        $UNITPRICE = '';
        foreach($item->barcodes as $barcode) {
            $serials = $barcode['serial_number'] ? $barcode['serial_number'] : $barcode['u_serial_number'];
            $ITEMUNIT = $barcode['product']['unit'];
            $UNITPRICE =$barcode['product']['price'];
        }
        // add data into template
        $shin[$key][] = [
            '_attributes' => [
                'operation' => 'Ret'
            ],
            'SERIALNUMBER' => $serials,
            'EXPIREDDATE' => $item['created_at']->format('Y-m-d'),
            'QUANTITY' => '1',
            'SNSIGN' => '-1',
        ];
        // SNHISTORY data

        $year = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['created_at'])->year;
        $month = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $item['created_at'])->month;


        $timeline[$key][] = [
            '_attributes' => [
                'operation' => 'Add'
            ],
            'KeyID' => $item['id'],
            'ITEMNO' => $item['transNu'],
            'QUANTITY' => '1',
            'ITEMUNIT' => $ITEMUNIT,
            'UNITRATIO' => '1',
            'ITEMRESERVED1' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED2' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED3' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED4' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED5' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED6' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED7' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED8' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED9' => '',
            'ITEMRESERVED10' => '',
            'UNITPRICE' => $UNITPRICE,
            'QTYCONTROL' => '0',
            'SNHISTORY' => $shin, // load the SNHISTORY template
        ];

        $array['TRANSACTIONS'] = [
            '_attributes' => [
                'OnError' => 'CONTINUE'
            ],
        ];

        $array['TRANSACTIONS']['WTRAN'] = [
            '_attributes' => [
                'operation' => 'Add',
                'REQUESTID' => '1',
            ],
            'TRANSFERID' => $item['id'],
            'TRANSACTIONID' => '',
            'TRANSFERNO' => $item['id'],
            'TRANSFERDATE' => $item['created_at']->format('Y-m-d'),
            'DESCRIPTION' => $item['description'],
            'FROMWHID' => $month,
            'TOWHID' => '',
            'FROMWHADDRESS' => '',
            'TOWHADDRESS' => '',
        ];

        $array['TRANSACTIONS']['WTRAN']['ITEMLINE'] = $timeline;

    }
    //data here

    $filename = 'internalTransits.xml';
    $result = ArrayToXml::convert($array, [
        'rootElementName' => 'NMEXML',
        '_attributes' => [
            'EximID'=> "13037",
            'BranchCode'=> $barcode['outlet'][0]['code'],
            'ACCOUNTANTCOPYID'=> ""
        ]
    ]);
    Storage::disk('local')->put($filename, $result);
    $fullPath = url('exports', $filename);

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $fullPath
    ]);
}
```

## Question

How can I get correct relationship data and place them in `ITEMLINE` arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I've changed my `SNHISTORY` code to:

```
$a = $item->barcodes;
$grouped = $a->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
    return [
        'SNHISTORY' => [
            '_attributes' => [
                'operation' => 'Ret'
            ],
            'SERIALNUMBER' => $item['serial_number'] ? $item['serial_number'] : $item['u_serial_number'],
            'EXPIREDDATE' => $item['created_at']->format('Y-m-d'),
            'QUANTITY' => '1',
            'SNSIGN' => '-1',
        ],
        'ITEMUNIT' => $item['product']['unit'],
        'UNITPRICE' => $item['product']['price'],
    ];
});
```

and it `$timeline` I've placed `$grouped->toArray()` like:

```
$timeline[$key][] = [
    '_attributes' => [
        'operation' => 'Add'
    ],
    'KeyID' => $item['id'],
    'ITEMNO' => $item['transNu'],
    'QUANTITY' => '1',
    'ITEMUNIT' => $barcode['product']['unit'],
    'UNITRATIO' => '1',
    'ITEMRESERVED1' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED2' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED3' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED4' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED5' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED6' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED7' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED8' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED9' => '',
    'ITEMRESERVED10' => '',
    'UNITPRICE' => $barcode['product']['price'],
    'QTYCONTROL' => '0',
    'SNHISTORY' => $grouped->toArray(), //here
];
```

and the problem solved, I can get my model relationships array with my desire template as follow:

```
<NMEXML EximID="13037" BranchCode="1450645381" ACCOUNTANTCOPYID="">
    <TRANSACTIONS OnError="CONTINUE">
        <WTRAN operation="Add" REQUESTID="1">
            <TRANSFERID>3</TRANSFERID>
            <TRANSACTIONID />
            <TRANSFERNO>3</TRANSFERNO>
            <TRANSFERDATE>2020-08-22</TRANSFERDATE>
            <DESCRIPTION>232547544</DESCRIPTION>
            <FROMWHID>8</FROMWHID>
            <TOWHID />
            <FROMWHADDRESS />
            <TOWHADDRESS />
            <ITEMLINE operation="Add">
                <KeyID>1</KeyID>
                <ITEMNO>6951919696</ITEMNO>
                <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
                <ITEMUNIT>Unit</ITEMUNIT>
                <UNITRATIO>1</UNITRATIO>
                <ITEMRESERVED1 />
                <ITEMRESERVED2 />
                <ITEMRESERVED3 />
                <ITEMRESERVED4 />
                <ITEMRESERVED5 />
                <ITEMRESERVED6 />
                <ITEMRESERVED7 />
                <ITEMRESERVED8 />
                <ITEMRESERVED9 />
                <ITEMRESERVED10 />
                <UNITPRICE>2500000</UNITPRICE>
                <QTYCONTROL>0</QTYCONTROL>
                <SNHISTORY>
                    <SNHISTORY operation="Ret">
                        <SERIALNUMBER>74122681</SERIALNUMBER>
                        <EXPIREDDATE>2020-08-21</EXPIREDDATE>
                        <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
                        <SNSIGN>-1</SNSIGN>
                    </SNHISTORY>
                    <SNHISTORY operation="Ret">
                        <SERIALNUMBER>658532125</SERIALNUMBER>
                        <EXPIREDDATE>2020-08-21</EXPIREDDATE>
                        <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
                        <SNSIGN>-1</SNSIGN>
                    </SNHISTORY>
                </SNHISTORY>
            </ITEMLINE>
            <ITEMLINE operation="Add">
                <KeyID>2</KeyID>
                <ITEMNO>9532880976</ITEMNO>
                <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
                <ITEMUNIT>Pcs</ITEMUNIT>
                <UNITRATIO>1</UNITRATIO>
                <ITEMRESERVED1 />
                <ITEMRESERVED2 />
                <ITEMRESERVED3 />
                <ITEMRESERVED4 />
                <ITEMRESERVED5 />
                <ITEMRESERVED6 />
                <ITEMRESERVED7 />
                <ITEMRESERVED8 />
                <ITEMRESERVED9 />
                <ITEMRESERVED10 />
                <UNITPRICE>50000000</UNITPRICE>
                <QTYCONTROL>0</QTYCONTROL>
                <SNHISTORY>
                    <SNHISTORY operation="Ret">
                        <SERIALNUMBER>454874152</SERIALNUMBER>
                        <EXPIREDDATE>2020-08-21</EXPIREDDATE>
                        <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
                        <SNSIGN>-1</SNSIGN>
                    </SNHISTORY>
                </SNHISTORY>
            </ITEMLINE>
            <ITEMLINE operation="Add">
                <KeyID>3</KeyID>
                <ITEMNO>2124086153</ITEMNO>
                <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
                <ITEMUNIT>Box</ITEMUNIT>
                <UNITRATIO>1</UNITRATIO>
                <ITEMRESERVED1 />
                <ITEMRESERVED2 />
                <ITEMRESERVED3 />
                <ITEMRESERVED4 />
                <ITEMRESERVED5 />
                <ITEMRESERVED6 />
                <ITEMRESERVED7 />
                <ITEMRESERVED8 />
                <ITEMRESERVED9 />
                <ITEMRESERVED10 />
                <UNITPRICE>23658000</UNITPRICE>
                <QTYCONTROL>0</QTYCONTROL>
                <SNHISTORY>
                    <SNHISTORY operation="Ret">
                        <SERIALNUMBER>232547544</SERIALNUMBER>
                        <EXPIREDDATE>2020-08-21</EXPIREDDATE>
                        <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
                        <SNSIGN>-1</SNSIGN>
                    </SNHISTORY>
                </SNHISTORY>
            </ITEMLINE>
        </WTRAN>
    </TRANSACTIONS>
</NMEXML>
```